# Java generics with upper bounded wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I'm just preparing for the Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 8 exam and I have some problems with generics and wildcards. I pretty well know that the code I'm submitting doesn't make a lot of sense and would not be written this way in 'real life' but it's an exercise for me.

1. First line: `((ArrayList<Exception>)exceptions).add(new Exception());` compiles

How can this one compile? `exceptions` is an `ArrayList` containing `FileNotFoundException` objects (or child classes). How can I add an `Exception` to an `ArrayList` supposed to hold only elements that are a subclass of `FileNotFoundException`? Without the cast the line doesn't compile. But even with the cast, exceptions should still be unable to contain superclasses of `FileNotFoundException`. Am I right or do I misunderstand something?

2. Line 2: `((ArrayList<IOException>)exceptions).add(new Exception());`
   doesn't compile

The difference between line 1 and 2 is that I now cast to an `IOException`, not an `Exception`. Exception is too 'wide' to be cast to `IOException`, sure. This should be the reason this line (same for line 5) does not compile. Right?

3. Line 3: `((ArrayList<IOException>)exceptions).add(new IOException());`

Compiles and I don't really understand why. Basically the same question as for line 1. `IOException` is superclass to `FileNotFoundException`, how can I put a member of a superclass in this `ArrayList`?

4. Line 4: `((ArrayList<Exception>)exceptions).add(new FileNotFoundException());`

Compiles. Same problem as Line 1.

```
package javaapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<? extends Throwable> exceptions = new ArrayList<FileNotFoundException>();

  ((ArrayList<Exception>)exceptions).add(new Exception());//1
  ((ArrayList<IOException>)exceptions).add(new Exception());//2,does not compile
  ((ArrayList<IOException>)exceptions).add(new IOException());//3
  ((ArrayList<Exception>)exceptions).add(new FileNotFoundException());//4
  ((ArrayList<FileNotFoundException>)exceptions).add(new
  Exception());//5,does not compile
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Answer (score 1):

That's why you get a "unsafe cast" compiler warning - because it's unsafe.

The answer to all your questions is badically:

1. when you cast the list, it's treated as that type for that invocation
2. you won't get an exception when putting the wrong type into a list, but you will get a ClassCastException when you take that object out of the list and assign it to a variable of the type of the list

Answer (score 0):

Casting a generic type to a "generic supertype" compiles because the list during runtime is just a list holding objects which are checked for being of type `Exception` at runtime (because it was cast to that); During runtime, there is no difference between `ArrayList<FileNotFoundException>` and `ArrayList<Exception>`, and the cast overrides the normal type-checking behavior. Thus, unlike e.g. C++ templates, references held by `ArrayList<FileNotFoundException>` are not actually "unable" to refer to `Exception` instances, since at runtime they're just generic "`Object`" references (pun intended).

`List<? extends Throwable>` means "a list of some sort of `Throwable` but I'm not quite sure exactly what": Therefore, initializing the reference with a `ArrayList<FileNotFoundException>` object is valid but is not terribly useful in real life: It means you can't add anything *to* the list because you "lose" what type it is allowed to contain after compile time.

On the other hand, if you wanted to be able to state "this list holds `FileNotFoundException` or some parent type thereof", you can define a `ArrayList<? super FileNotFoundException>` generic type. Thus, `ArrayList<? super FileNotFoundException> exceptions = new ArrayList<IOException>();` is valid and would allow you to add `FileNotFoundException` or `IOException` but not e.g. `Exception`.